# Swift Printing an Array in a table form String and also adding special characters

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, nsarray, stringbuilder

Lets assume i have this string

```swift
var stringCSV = "Beth,Charles,Danielle,Adam,Eric\n17945,10091,10088,3907,10132\n2,12,13,48,11";
```

And i converted it into a 2D Array

```swift
[["Beth", "Charles", "Danielle", "Adam", "Eric"], ["17945", "10091", "10088", "3907", "10132"], ["2", "12", "13", "48", "11"]]
```

Below is the code i used to convert the String into a 2D Array and sort it.

```swift
struct Person {
  let name: String
  let id: String
  let age: String
}

var csvFormatted = [[String]]()

stringCSV.enumerateLines { (line, _) in
  var res = line.split(separator: ",",omittingEmptySubsequences: false).map{ 
    String($0) 
  }
  for i in 0 ..< res.count {
    res[i] = res[i]
  }
  csvFormatted.append(res)
}

let properties = zip(csvFormatted[1],csvFormatted[2])
let namesAndProperties = zip(csvFormatted[0],properties)

let structArray = namesAndProperties.map { (name, properties) in
  return Person(name: name, id: properties.0, age: properties.1)
}

let sortedArray = structArray.sorted {
  return $0.name < $1.name
}

for i in sortedArray {
    print(i.name, i.id, i.age)
}
```

i get the below output

```swift
Adam 3907 48
Beth 17945 2
Charles 10091 12
Danielle 10088 13
Eric 10132 11
```

But I wont to understand and know how i can print the sorted array back to string, just like it was before i splitted it into an array and sorted it and including the special characters like "\n" and ",".

and achieve something the below

```swift
Adam,Beth,Charles,Danielle,Eric\n
3907,17945,10091,10088,10132\n
48,2,12,13,11
```

Comment: @son i wish i understood what you mean by saving the string into an internal property may be a reference or code may help

Comment: I we focus on only the first 2, do you want `"Adam,3907,48\nBeth,17945,2"` or `"Adam,Beth\n3907,17945\n48,2"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `map` for each property and join it to create a comma separated row. Then using the results in an array join again with a new line character.

```
let csv = [array.map(\.name).joined(separator: ","),
           array.map(\.id).joined(separator: ","),
           array.map(\.age).joined(separator: ",")]
   .joined(separator: "\n")
```

Comment: your answer does not print is the desired order, ive updated my question

Comment: @BigFire See my updated answer

Comment: its wierd i get this strange error from my playground `solution.swift:39:89: error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
     let csv : String = [sortedArray.map(\.name).joined(separator: ","),sortedArray.map(\.id).joined(separator:","),sortedArray.map(\.age).joined(separator: ",")].joined(separator: "\n")`

Comment: You are using the exact same code as in my answer and it works for me. Also when I copy all code from the question and run it together with my answer it works fine.